# Alternative to animation(forKey:) (now deprecated)?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, ios11

I am working with iOS 11 (for `ARKit`) and while many point to a sample app for `SceneKit` from Apple with a Fox, I am having problem with the extension it uses in that sample project ([file](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Fox/Listings/Swift_Common_SceneKitExtensions_swift.html)) to add animations:

```
extension CAAnimation {
    class func animationWithSceneNamed(_ name: String) -> CAAnimation? {
        var animation: CAAnimation?
        if let scene = SCNScene(named: name) {
            scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes({ (child, stop) in
                if child.animationKeys.count > 0 {
                    animation = child.animation(forKey: child.animationKeys.first!)
                    stop.initialize(to: true)
                }
            })
        }
        return animation
    }
}
```

It seems that this extension is very handy but I am not sure how to migrate this now that it is deprecated?  Is it built into `SceneKit` by default now?

The documentation didn't really show much info on why it was deprecated or where to go from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**: examples of how to use new APIs can be found in Apple's [sample game](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/scenekit-2017/) (search for `SCNAnimationPlayer`)

---

Even though `animation(forKey:)` and its sister methods that work with `CAAnimation` have been deprecated in `iOS11`, you can continue using them – everything will work.

But if you want to use new APIs and don't care about backwards compatibility (which you wouldn't need in the case of `ARKit` anyway, because it's only available since `iOS11`), read on.

The newly introduced `SCNAnimationPlayer` provides a more convenient API compared to its predecessors. It is now easier to work with animations in real time.
[This video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/?time=2036) from `WWDC2017` would be a good starting point to learn about it.

As a quick summary: `SCNAnimationPlayer` allows you to change animation's speed on the fly. It provides a more intuitive interface for animation playback using methods such as `play()` and `stop()` compared to adding and removing `CAAnimation`s.
You also can blend two animations together which, for example, can be used to make smooth transitions between them.

You can find examples of how to use all of this in the [Fox 2 game by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/scenekit-2017/).

---

Here's the extension you've posted adapted to use `SCNAnimationPlayer` (which you can find in the `Character` class in the Fox 2 sample project):

```
extension SCNAnimationPlayer {
    class func loadAnimation(fromSceneNamed sceneName: String) -> SCNAnimationPlayer {
        let scene = SCNScene( named: sceneName )!
        // find top level animation
        var animationPlayer: SCNAnimationPlayer! = nil
        scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (child, stop) in
            if !child.animationKeys.isEmpty {
                animationPlayer = child.animationPlayer(forKey: child.animationKeys[0])
                stop.pointee = true
            }
        }
        return animationPlayer
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

1. Load the animation and add it to the corresponding node

   ```
   let jumpAnimation = SCNAnimationPlayer.loadAnimation(fromSceneNamed: "jump.scn")
   jumpAnimation.stop() // stop it for now so that we can use it later when it's appropriate 
   model.addAnimationPlayer(jumpAnimation, forKey: "jump")
   ```
2. Use it!

   ```
   model.animationPlayer(forKey: "jump")?.play()
   ```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I've followed your link and done exactly that, replacing my CAAnimation code with SCNAnimationPlayer but I cannot get it to play for the life of me. The mesh jumps to the first frame of the animation so I know it's loading it. I can log the animation and see the right number of frames, but play() does nothing.     

The same animation using CAAnimation works fine. Anything I can test for?

Answer (score 2):

Lësha Turkowski's answer without force unwraps.

```
extension SCNAnimationPlayer {

    class func loadAnimationPlayer(from sceneName: String) -> SCNAnimationPlayer? {
        var animationPlayer: SCNAnimationPlayer?

        if let scene = SCNScene(named: sceneName) {
            scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (child, stop) in
                if !child.animationKeys.isEmpty {
                    animationPlayer = child.animationPlayer(forKey: child.animationKeys[0])
                    stop.pointee = true
                }
            }
        }

        return animationPlayer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of **SwiftUI and SceneKit**

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var isPlayingAnimation: Bool

let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/TestScene.scn")!

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    let scnView = SCNView()
    return scnView
}

func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
    scnView.scene = scene

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    controlAnimation(isAnimating: isPlayingAnimation, nodeName: "TestNode", animationName: "TestAnimationName")
}

func controlAnimation(isAnimating: Bool, nodeName: String, animationName: String) {
    guard let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: nodeName, recursively: true) else {  return }
    guard let animationPlayer: SCNAnimationPlayer = node.animationPlayer(forKey: animationName) else {  return }
    if isAnimating {
        print("Play Animation")
        animationPlayer.play()
    } else {
        print("Stop Animation")
        animationPlayer.stop()
    }
}
}

struct DogAnimation_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScenekitView(isPlayingAnimation: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A 2023 example.

I load typical animations like this:

```
func simpleLoadAnim(filename: String) -> SCNAnimationPlayer {
    let s = SCNScene(named: filename)!
    let n = s.rootNode.childNodes.filter({!$0.animationKeys.isEmpty}).first!
    return n.animationPlayer(forKey: n.animationKeys.first!)!
}
```

So,

```
laugh = simpleLoadAnim(filename: "animeLaugh") // animeLaugh.dae
giggle = simpleLoadAnim(filename: "animeGiggle")
```

You then, **step one**, have to add them to the character:

```
sally.addAnimationPlayer(laugh, forKey: "laugh")
sally.addAnimationPlayer(giggle, forKey: "giggle")
```

very typically you would have only one going at a time. So set the weights, **step two**.

```
laugh.blendFactor = 1
giggle.blendFactor = 0
```

to play or stop an `SCNAnimationPlayer` it's just **step three**

```
laugh.play()
giggle.stop()
```

Almost certainly, you will have (100s of lines) of your own code to blend between animations (which might take only a short time, 0.1 secs, or may take a second or so). To do so, you would use `SCNAction.customAction`.

If you prefer you can access the animation, on, the character (sally) using the keys. But really the "whole point" is you can just start, stop, etc etc the `SCNAnimationPlayer`.

You will also have lots of code to set up the `SCNAnimationPlayer` how you like (speed, looping, mirrored, etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc)

You will need THIS very critical answer to get collada files (must be separate character / anim files) working properly https://stackoverflow.com/a/75093081/294884

Once you have the various `SCNAnimationPlayer` animations working properly, it is quite easy to use, run, blend etc animes.

The essential sequence is

1. each anime must be in its own .dae file
2. load each anime files in to a `SCNAnimationPlayer`
3. "add" all the animes to the character in question
4. program the blends
5. then simply `play()` or `stop()` the actual `SCNAnimationPlayer` items (don't bother using the keys on the character, it's a bit pointless)

Comment: Do you have any questions regarding this article?