# How to setup bone hierarchy for SCNSkinner from glb data?

Tags: swift, graphics, scenekit, skeletal-animation, skeletal-mesh

I'm trying to show a 3d model of a human body scan in SceneKit. The model is stored in a glb file. Because SceneKit does not support the import of that file format I manually read the file in. I'm trying to use the SCNSkinner from SceneKit to rig the model with the Mixamo-rig included in the glb file. The model is correctly shown as long as I don't apply any bone positions unequal (0, 0, 0), rotations or set boneInverseBindTransforms unequal the Identity matrix. But as soon as I apply any of the afore mentioned properties, the model starts to look unnatural.

Here is the code to create the SCNSkinner object:

```
private func createSCNSkinnerFrom(bgArmature: BgArmature, baseGeometry: SCNGeometry) -> SCNSkinner? {
        var joints: [UInt8] = bgArmature.mesh.joints.joined().map { element in UInt8(element) }
        var weights: [Float] = bgArmature.mesh.weights.joined().map { element in element }
        
        let bones: [SCNNode] = self.createBoneNodesList(bgRig: bgArmature.rig!)
    
        let boneIndicesData = Data(bytesNoCopy: &joints, count: joints.count * MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size, deallocator: .none)
        let boneIndicesGeometrySource = SCNGeometrySource(data: boneIndicesData, semantic: .boneIndices, vectorCount: joints.count/4, usesFloatComponents: false, componentsPerVector: 4, bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size, dataOffset: 0, dataStride: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size * 4)
        
        let boneWeightsData = Data(bytesNoCopy: &weights, count: weights.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.size, deallocator: .none)
        let boneWeightsGeometrySource = SCNGeometrySource(data: boneWeightsData, semantic: .boneWeights, vectorCount: weights.count/4, usesFloatComponents: true, componentsPerVector: 4, bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size, dataOffset: 0, dataStride: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4)
        
        let boneInverseBindTransforms: [NSValue]? = self.createListOfBoneInverseBindTransforms(bgBones: bgArmature.rig!.bones)
        
        let skinner = SCNSkinner(baseGeometry: baseGeometry,
                                 bones: bones,
                                 boneInverseBindTransforms: boneInverseBindTransforms,
                                 boneWeights: boneWeightsGeometrySource,
                                 boneIndices: boneIndicesGeometrySource)
        return skinner
    }
```

Here the function to create a bone node and the list of bones:

```
private func createBoneNodeWithoutChildren(bgBone: BgBone) -> SCNNode {
        let bone = SCNNode()
        if let name = bgBone.name {
            bone.name = name
        }
        if let translation = bgBone.translation {
            bone.simdPosition = SIMD3<Float>(translation[0]!, translation[1]!, translation[2]!) 
        }
        if let rotation = bgBone.rotation {
            bone.simdOrientation = simd_quatf(ix: rotation[0]!, iy: rotation[1]!, iz: rotation[2]!, r: rotation[3]!)
        }
        if let scale = bgBone.scale {
            bone.simdScale = SIMD3<Float>(scale[0]!, scale[1]!, scale[2]!)
        }
        return bone
    }

private func createBoneNodesList(bgRig: BgRig) -> [SCNNode] {
        var bonesList: [SCNNode] = []
        for bone in bgRig.bones {
            bonesList.append(self.createBoneNodeWithoutChildren(bgBone: bone))
        }
        return bonesList
    }
```

The function to create the boneInverseTransforms:

```
private func createListOfBoneInverseBindTransforms(bgBones: [BgBone]!) -> [NSValue]? {
        var boneInverseBindTransforms: [NSValue]? = []
        for bone in bgBones {
            boneInverseBindTransforms?.append(NSValue(scnMatrix4: bone.inverseBindMatrix!.getSCNMatrix4()))
        }
        return boneInverseBindTransforms
    }
```

And the BgBone class with the BgMat4 struct:

```
class BgBone {
    var index: Int?
    var children: [Int?]?
    var name: String?
    var rotation: [Float?]?
    var scale: [Float?]?
    var translation: [Float?]?
    var inverseBindMatrix: BgMat4?
    
    init(index: Int? = nil, children: [Int?]? = nil, name: String? = nil, rotation: [Float?]? = nil, scale: [Float?]? = nil, translation: [Float?]? = nil) {
        self.index = index
        self.children = children
        self.name = name
        self.rotation = rotation
        self.scale = scale
        self.translation = translation
    }
}

struct BgMat4: sizeable {
    var r1c1: Float
    var r2c1: Float
    var r3c1: Float
    var r4c1: Float
    
    var r1c2: Float
    var r2c2: Float
    var r3c2: Float
    var r4c2: Float
    
    var r1c3: Float
    var r2c3: Float
    var r3c3: Float
    var r4c3: Float
    
    var r1c4: Float
    var r2c4: Float
    var r3c4: Float
    var r4c4: Float
    
    init(fromData: Data) {
        /// Accessors of matrix type have data stored in column-major order; start of each column MUST be aligned to 4-byte boundaries.
        /// Specifically, when ROWS * SIZE_OF_COMPONENT (where ROWS is the number of rows of the matrix) is not a multiple of 4,
        /// then (ROWS * SIZE_OF_COMPONENT) % 4 padding bytes MUST be inserted at the end of each column.
        self.r1c1 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r2c1 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 4, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r3c1 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 8, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r4c1 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 12, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r1c2 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 16, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r2c2 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 20, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r3c2 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 24, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r4c2 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 28, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r1c3 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 32, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r2c3 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 36, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r3c3 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 40, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r4c3 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 44, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r1c4 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 48, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r2c4 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 52, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r3c4 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 56, as: Float32.self) }
        self.r4c4 = fromData.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in rawBuffer.load(fromByteOffset: 60, as: Float32.self) }
    }
    
    func getSCNMatrix4() -> SCNMatrix4 {
        return SCNMatrix4(m11: self.r1c1,
                          m12: self.r2c1,
                          m13: self.r3c1,
                          m14: self.r4c1,
                          m21: self.r1c2,
                          m22: self.r2c2,
                          m23: self.r3c2,
                          m24: self.r4c2,
                          m31: self.r1c3,
                          m32: self.r2c3,
                          m33: self.r3c3,
                          m34: self.r4c3,
                          m41: self.r1c4,
                          m42: self.r2c4,
                          m43: self.r3c4,
                          m44: self.r4c4)
    }
}
```

With this code the model looks like this:
[image: Model with applied Position, rotation and bindInverseTransformation]

With Positions==(0, 0, 0), Rotation(0, 0, 0), bindInverseTransformation=Identity it looks like this:
[image]

But with the Positions, Rotations and bindInverseTransformations applied I expect the model to be in the A-Pose (similar to the following image):
[image]

**What am I doing wrong with my bones (SCNNodes) or skinner (SCNSkinner) object?**

Comment: probably this here gives you an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090481/how-to-get-a-ordinary-mixamo-character-animation-working-in-scenekit

Comment: Thank you. This will help for the animation part of my project.