# Can I use the same animation model on multiple 3D characters in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I would like to be able to programmatically apply the same animation to multiple characters.

Is this something possible in SceneKit?

Comment: how do you use animations for your project? i.Ex a rigged collada with the character model and some separate animation collada files? is your goal to apply the animation to multiple characters in a way that they all do exactly the same at the same time or is your goal to apply the animation at some specific time for each character? are your characters all identical or are they different models? This answer here probably gives you some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090481/how-to-get-a-ordinary-mixamo-character-animation-working-in-scenekit/75093081#75093081