# Scenekit start/stop Skeletal animation of imported USDZ

Tags: scenekit, skeletal-animation

Sorry,

first time I have this need and unable to find any valuable help so far.

Scenekit preview of the USDZ in Xcode is able to play the animation and the scene graph is below

[image]

I usualy have anymations with no bones and I do play them with something like

```
let player = backgroundNode.childNode(withName: "Geom", recursively: true)!.animationPlayer(forKey: "transform")
player?.stop()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(0), execute: {player?.play()})
```

What I use to start and stop the Skeletal animation?

What is the name of the animation in this case?

What is the node name I have to choose which contains the animation?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi czane, I dont't have an out of the Box Solution to your case (I would need the project to figure it out) but here you might find some information on how to make a rigged character move: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090481/how-to-get-a-ordinary-mixamo-character-animation-working-in-scenekit/75093081#75093081

Comment: Thanks, I understand there is no an out of the box functionality for that too bad. Thanks anyway