Add animation from a separate file in SceneKit, iOS
I have a model of a person in glb format, that I import to SceneKit through GLTFKit2.

I also have an animation for that model living in a separate fbx file. I convert it to dae in Blender.
Their hierarchies are the same, so I go through each animation in my animation file and add it to a corresponding node in my model
func applyAnimation(on scene: SCNScene) {
    guard
      let animationSource = getAnimationSource()
    else {
      return
    }

    let identifiers = animationSource.identifiersOfEntries(
      withClass: SCNAnimation.self
    )

    identifiers.forEach {
      guard
        let animation = animationSource.entryWithIdentifier($0, withClass: SCNAnimation.self)
      else {
        return
      }

      guard
        let fullKeyPath = animation.keyPath,
        let keyPath = fullKeyPath.dropFirst().components(separatedBy: ".").first
      else {
        return
      }

      animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude

      guard
        let node = find(keypath: keyPath, in: scene.rootNode)
      else {
        return
      }
      normalize(node: node)
      node.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animationKey-\(fullKeyPath)")
    }
  }

func find(keypath: String, in node: SCNNode) -> SCNNode? {
    if node.name == keypath {
      return node
    }
    if let node = node.childNodes.first(
      where: {
        $0.name == keypath
      }
    ) {
      return node
    }

    for childNode in node.childNodes {
      if let node = find(keypath: keypath, in: childNode) {
        return node
      }
    }

    return nil
  }

Unfortunately, once I apply the animation, my model becomes really distorted. As if the scale of my animation is a lot bigger, than of my model. Each bone on my model drifts apart, but the hierarchy stays intact and the animation is correct (for geometry, that no longer looks like my model at all)

Thinking that the issue is in the scale/coordinates of my animation, I tried to normalize both my model and animation, but it doesn't seem like I'm able to modify any properties of my animation, as the result looks all the same.
In Blender, both animation file and the model file have the same size/scale.
What could be the way to adjust animation transformation, so that it aligns with my model? Or what else could be wrong with my flow?
func normalizeAllNodes(for node: SCNNode) {
    for node in node.childNodes {
      normalize(node: node)
      normalizeAllNodes(for: node)
    }
  }

  // Normalize coordinates
  func normalize(node: SCNNode) {
    node.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity
    node.position = SCNVector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    node.rotation = SCNVector4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    node.scale = SCNVector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
  }

Final method looks like this
public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let view = SCNView()

    guard
      let modelUrl = Bundle.main.url(
        forResource: "model",
        withExtension: "glb"
      )
    else {
      return view
    }

    extractSceneSource(from: modelUrl) { source in
      guard
        let scene = source?.defaultScene
      else {
        return
      }
      normalizeAllNodes(for: scene.rootNode)
      printNodeHierarchy(node: scene.rootNode)
      applyAnimation(on: scene)

      view.scene = scene
    }

    view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    view.allowsCameraControl = true
    view.showsStatistics = true
    view.backgroundColor = .black

    return view
  }


From the loaded animation information, use only rotation and ignore the scale and position. Each loader/exporter does some processing, so its better to export everything in dae.

This is also my opinion. Export everything in DAE (there might be some mismatch when using GLT with DAE in your App). Export the Animation Files without the Rig. But there are a few steps to care about. Here is an article that might help you. It's for Mixamo based characters, but should work as well in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090481/how-to-get-a-ordinary-mixamo-character-animation-working-in-scenekit/75093081#75093081

@codetiger unfortunately my model provider only returns glb

@ZAY thanks a lot for pointing me to that SO question, I followed your steps and got mixamo models working as expected. However my converted glb model still behaves the same, which leads me to think that my glb converter introduces issues to the geometry

by default, XCode Projects in combination with SceneKit can only handle .obj and .dae Files. Both you can convert to the .scn format, which provides a little bit better loading performence (Apples Docs.)
I highly recommend you to get rid of the GLT Format here. Convert your Models using Blender to a Collada (.dae) and then use it in your App.

Unless you are loading user uploaded models dynamically in your app, it does not makes sense using any other format than scn. The Xcode editor allows you to convert the formats, so why add GLT loading library to your app.

@codetiger that's exactly what I need to do, download glb models from a provider's api

@ArtemMisesin am into the same situation and trying to limit with DAE and OBJ for now. But I'll cross the same situation of supporting more formats. Please share your experience :)

@ZAY after hours of investigating this, applying the animation stretches the nodes 100x away from each other, stretching the textures. I confirmed this when manually multiplying SCNNode.position by 100 and seeing exactly the same result. I then looked into how my provider's web sdk handles this in TS and they multiply each animation's position value by 0.01 to get rid of the stretching factor. Now lies the question how I can achieve the same result. I'm trying to write a Python script to change the coordinates on each animation keyframe, but can't get my animation to change

Can you provide a Minimal Reproducable Example for download?
